# Chess.js - Get a list/existing list of all possible chess notations

Tags: angular, chess

I have a string, and I want to check if it is a valid chess algebraic notation.
chess.js has the moves() function which lists all the LEGAL moves, but I want to check for all moves, even if they aren't legal in the current position.
If there is an existing dictionary of all the possible chess moves or a package for that I can install it as well if there isn't a solution in chess.js

Here is an example of chess.moves:

```
const chess = new Chess()
chess.moves()
// -> ['a3', 'a4', 'b3', 'b4', 'c3', 'c4', 'd3', 'd4', 'e3', 'e4',
//     'f3', 'f4', 'g3', 'g4', 'h3', 'h4', 'Na3', 'Nc3', 'Nf3', 'Nh3']
```

and here is an example of the start of all chess algbraic notations (which I am looking for)

```
['a1','a2','a3',...,'Ba1','Ba2',...,'a8=Q',...,'a8=N+']
```

Comment: You should include markdown snippets of the relevant strings and any other code context.

Comment: I expanded on the question, if there is anything else that is unclear please let me know.

Comment: So moves which are not legal include taking an already captured piece and place it back on the board, move a rook diagonally, change the color of a piece, ...etc. That will produce a *huge* number of moves.

Comment: i'm aware that it will produce a huge number of moves, and I am fine with that. It is what I am looking for to use in my project

Comment: There are billions of moves like that. It is not feasible. Please explain how this could ever be useful. You'll have at least to define what is an "illegal move". This is ambiguous. Is replacing all your pawns with queens such an illegal move??

Comment: I am making a chess game online, where the player inputs a chess notation, and I want to display different error messages. I want differing error messages on whether the move is illegal or the notation is illegal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [this repo](https://github.com/jacksonthall22/SAN-strings) to generate all possible SAN moves. I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but I'll include an excerpt from my README:

> This simple script generates all 37,302 possible Standard Algebraic Notation (SAN) strings for chess moves, with some special logic to avoid listing SAN strings that can never actually occur for geometric reasons.

> The only considerations beyond the naive approach of "move every piece from every square to every other legal square" has to do with discriminators: some are legal syntactically but could never occur. The logic is slightly different for each piece, which I describe below.

Perhaps [`san_strings.txt`](https://github.com/jacksonthall22/SAN-strings/blob/main/san_strings.txt) or [`san_strings_with_symbols.txt`](https://github.com/jacksonthall22/SAN-strings/blob/main/san_strings_with_symbols.txt) is the list you're looking for.

Looking briefly at the other answers posted here, it seems like they don't consider discriminators at all. This takes a surprising amount of logic to get right, which I discuss at length in the README.

Comment: Wow! I am really impressed with your work and the depth you went into, must have been a fun project! I am accepting your answer instead of mine because it is indeed more accurate. Thanks!

Comment: @INTODAN Glad it might actually help someone! I was surprised at how small the total number of moves is even with all combinations of trailing + and # symbols, indeed it seems easier to validate against the full list instead of using complex regex statements. I did have fun coding it!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all the moves by nesting loops:

```
const files = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];
const ranks = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'];
const pieces = ['p', 'n', 'b', 'r', 'q', 'k'];

const allMoves = [];

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < ranks.length; j++) {
    const startSquare = files[i] + ranks[j];
    
    for (let k = 0; k < files.length; k++) {
      for (let l = 0; l < ranks.length; l++) {
        const endSquare = files[k] + ranks[l];
        
        for (let m = 0; m < pieces.length; m++) {
          const piece = pieces[m];
          
          // Add normal move
          allMoves.push(`${piece}${startSquare}-${endSquare}`);
          
          // Add promotion moves
          if (piece === 'p' && (ranks[j] === '7' || ranks[l] === '1')) {
            allMoves.push(`${startSquare}-${endSquare}=Q`);
            allMoves.push(`${startSquare}-${endSquare}=R`);
            allMoves.push(`${startSquare}-${endSquare}=B`);
            allMoves.push(`${startSquare}-${endSquare}=N`);
          }
          
          // Add check and checkmate indicators
          allMoves.push(`${piece}${startSquare}-${endSquare}+`);
          allMoves.push(`${piece}${startSquare}-${endSquare}#`);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(allMoves);
```

Comment: it theoretically looks ok, but I am afraid that there is some rare notation that we don't know about, so I was wondering whether there was some definitive answer as to every notation possible in chess while being sure we didn't miss anything.

Comment: I posted an improvement, I hope it covers all the moves but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

I made an improvement upon Wandrille's answer to include more special cases, if I missed anything let me know.

```
public readonly notationDict: string[] = [];
public readonly letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];
public readonly numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'];
public readonly pieces = ['K', 'Q', 'B', 'N', 'R', '']; // empty is pawn
public readonly takes = 'x';
public readonly promotes = '=';
public readonly checks = ['+', '#'];
 for (let i = 0; i < this.letters.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < this.numbers.length; j++) {
    const startSquare = this.letters[i] + this.numbers[j];
    const startLetter = this.letters[i];
    const startNumber = this.numbers[j];
    for (let k = 0; k < this.letters.length; k++) {
      for (let l = 0; l < this.numbers.length; l++) {
        const endSquare = this.letters[k] + this.numbers[l];
        const endLetter = this.letters[k];
        const endNumber = this.numbers[l];
        for (let m = 0; m < this.pieces.length; m++) {
          const piece = this.pieces[m];
          // move with large notation
          this.notationDict.push(piece + startSquare + endSquare);

          // takes with large notation
          this.notationDict.push(piece + startSquare + this.takes + endSquare);

          // move with medium notation
          this.notationDict.push(piece + startLetter + endSquare);

          if(piece != ''){
            this.notationDict.push(piece + startNumber + endSquare);
          }

          // takes with medium notation
          this.notationDict.push(piece + startLetter + this.takes + endSquare);

          if(piece != ''){
            this.notationDict.push(piece + startNumber + this.takes + endSquare);
          }

          // move with small notation
          this.notationDict.push(piece + endSquare);

          // takes with small notation
          this.notationDict.push(piece + this.takes + endSquare);

          // Add promotion moves
          if(piece == '' && (endNumber == '8' || endNumber == '1')){
            for (let w = 0; w<this.pieces.length-1; w++) {
              let promotedPiece = this.pieces[w];

              // promotion with large notation
              this.notationDict.push(startSquare + endSquare + this.promotes + promotedPiece)

              // takes promotion with large notation
              this.notationDict.push(startSquare + this.takes + endSquare + this.promotes + promotedPiece);

              // promotion with medium notation
              this.notationDict.push(startLetter + endSquare + this.promotes + promotedPiece)

              // takes promotion with medium notation
              this.notationDict.push(startLetter + this.takes + endSquare + this.promotes + promotedPiece);

              // promotion with small notation
              this.notationDict.push(endSquare + this.promotes + promotedPiece);

              // takes promotion with small notation
              this.notationDict.push(this.takes + endSquare + this.promotes + promotedPiece);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
// Adding all the checks
const prevDict = [...this.notationDict];
for (let i=0; i<prevDict.length; i++){
  for (let j=0; j<this.checks.length; j++){
    this.notationDict.push(prevDict[i] + this.checks[j]);
  }
}
```